# Type unicode character using python variable

Tags: python, unicode

The code point of '' in hex is `'0001f40d'`, and I store this code point in variable `hex_snake`.
Then I want to call this icon using `'\Uhex_snake'` but got an error. Any ideas on expanding variables inside of quotes?

Comment: Depending on your use-case, you might want to store the name of the character instead: `unicodedata.name('SNAKE') == ''`.

Comment: Which error do you get? Could you edit your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\U` escape code can only be used in string literals, and must be followed by eight hexadecimal digits between 00000000-0010FFFF.  But you can just store the character in your variable instead and print with f-strings:

```
>>> snake = '\U0001f40d'  # or '\N{SNAKE}' or chr(0x1f40d)
>>> print(f'snake = {snake}')
snake =
```

If you have hex digits in a string and don't want to change, the following works, but is more complicated:

```
>>> snake = '0001f40d'
>>> print(f'snake = {chr(int(snake,16))}')
snake =
```

Answer (score 1):

The given string can be turned into an `int`, which can then be used as an argument for `chr`.

```
>>> x = '0001f40d'
>>> chr(int(x, base=16))
''
```

Comment: It works this way. However, I’m just curious that is there a way to achieve this using ```\Ux```? I know in shell scripting that you can do something like ```\U${x}```. So I just want to know if python has this feature as well.

Comment: `\U` is part of the syntax for a literal; it's not a lookup function to use with runtime data.